# place all object files into the same directory for a distributed sources in a makefile

Tags: makefile

My source code is not centralized. I want to put all of my objects into a single directory, `./build/obj`.

Here is what I have so far

```
ROOT=.

BUILDDIR=$(ROOT)/build
BINDIR=$(BUILDDIR)/bin
OBJDIR=$(BUILDDIR)/obj
CC=$(XCOMPILE)gcc
BIN=my-reader

CFLAGS+=\
        -Wall \
        -Wextra \
        -Werror \
        -pedantic \
        -std=gnu11 \
        $(INCLUDE)

SRCDIRS+=\
         $(ROOT)/src \
         $(ROOT)/../../folder0/folder01/src \
         $(ROOT)/../../folder0/folder02/src \
         $(ROOT)/../../folder1/folder03/folder04/i2c/src \
         $(ROOT)/../../folder1/folder03/folder04/spi/src \
         $(ROOT)/../../folder1/folder03/folder04/system/src \
         $(ROOT)/../../folder2/folder03/folder04/chip-1-api/src \
         $(ROOT)/../../folder2/folder03/folder04/chip-2-api/src

DEPDIRS+=\
         $(SRCDIRS)

SRC+=$(shell find $(SRCDIRS) -type f -name "*\.c")
DEP+=$(shell find $(DEPDIRS) -type f -name "*\.h")

OBJ=$(patsubst %.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SRC))
INCLUDE=$(foreach d, $(DEP),-I $(dir $d))

test:
    echo $(SRC)

all: CFLAGS+=-O3
all: _all

debug: CFLAGS+=-ggdb
debug: CPPFLAGS+=-DDEBUG
debug: _all

_all: $(BINDIR) $(BINDIR)/$(BIN)

$(BINDIR)/$(BIN): $(OBJ) | $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(BINDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEP)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)
```

This doesn't exactly work for me, since it creates some of the files and directories where makefile is located. What I really want is for all `.o` files to be in `./build/obj`. I spend several days trying to figure out if there is a generic way of doing it, but it looks like there isn't one. As far as I understand, in order to put all of my files into `./build/obj` directory I need to create a specific target for each of them, which defeats the purpose of using a generic makefile. Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible? I've seen people generating `.dep` (which have custom targets in them) files and then including them into makefiles. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that. I'd appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple, [using VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html).  First, you have to make sure your `OBJS` variable contains what you want to build.  Currently you have this:

```
OBJ=$(patsubst %.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SRC))
```

which is wrong, because `SRC` contains paths like `./../../folder0/folder02/src/foobar.c` which means after the `patsubst` you'll get paths like `./build/obj/./../../folder0/folder02/src/foobar.o` which is clearly not what you want.  Use this instead:

```
OBJ = $(patsubst %.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(notdir $(SRC)))
```

which for every source file `somepath/foobar.c`, regardless of the value of *somepath*, will give you `./build/obj/foobar.o` which is what you want.

Then, keep your rule that builds this .o from a .c file.  Finally use VPATH to tell make where to look for source files if they don't exist in the local directory:

```
VPATH = $(SRCDIRS)
```

That's all you need to do.

I should point out that your `INCLUDES` is kind of broken: you'll have massive numbers of duplicate directories added with `-I`.  Instead of this:

```
INCLUDE=$(foreach d, $(DEP),-I $(dir $d))
```

You should use:

```
INCLUDE = $(addprefix -I,$(sort $(dir $(DEP)))
```

The `sort` function will also uniquify, and you don't need the `foreach` because most functions in make take multiple words and operate on all of them.

As a final note, you should be using `:=` rather than `=`, it will be *much* more efficient.  The way you have it written here every single time these variables are expanded it will re-run the `find` operations etc.  Stick an `echo find 1>&2;` in your `shell` function invocations before the `find`, and see how many times it's run...

Oh, then a really-final note: the way you have this set up now every single source file will rebuild whenever any header file changes (you have added `$(DEPS)` as a prerequisite of the `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` target).  Maybe that's what you want, but it's unusual.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. How would I add exact dependencies per each file instead of how I have it now?

Comment: You can read this for some thoughts: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/  If you have questions it's best to ask a new question on SO, or else contact help-make@gnu.org for assistance, rather than asking in comments here.

Comment: Ok. Will do so in the future.